# Linux ECHO output of a ECHO variable

Tags: variable, echo

I have a variable (`var`) which return value as `VAR1` (`$var` has the value `VAR1`).
There is an input file which has `VAR1` defined (`VAR1=ABCDEF`)

How can I use `echo` to get the value `ABCDEF` using `$var`??

I tried `echo $(echo $var)` and many other options, but I always get output as `VAR1` or `echo VAR1` but never `ABCDEF`. I used `source` in file with `VAR1` declared, tried in command prompt etc.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you are using the `bash` shell:

```
$ source ./file
$ echo "$VAR1"
ABCDEF
$ var=VAR1
$ echo "${!var}"
ABCDEF
```

By using `${!var}` you use *variable indirection* in `bash`.  The value of the variable `var` is used to get the name of the variable to expand.

---

In `bash` you could also use a name reference variable:

```
$ source ./file
$ echo "$VAR1"
ABCDEF
$ declare -n var="VAR1"
$ echo "$var"
ABCDEF
```

Here, the `var` variable refers to the `VAR1` variable, so `$var` will expand to whatever `$VAR1` expands to.

Name references are originally a `ksh` feature, and in that shell they are declare with `typeset -n`.

Name references are extremely useful fo passing references to arrays in calls to shell functions.

---

In any `sh` shell:

```
$ . ./file
$ echo "$VAR1"
ABCDEF
$ var=VAR1
$ eval "echo \"\$$var\""
ABCDEF
```

The `eval` utility takes a string which it will re-evaluate.  Here, we give it the string `echo "$VAR1"` (after expansion of `$var`).

The issue with `eval` is that it's easy to introduce errors or vulnerabilities with it, by carelessly creating its argument string.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using `bash`, you can accomplish this easily with an indirect reference:

```
$ foo=bar
$ bar=magicword
$ printf "%s\n" "${!foo}"
magicword
```

The syntax `$var` (or `${var}`) yields the contents of the variable `var`.

The syntax `${!var}` yields the contents of the variable *named in* `var`.